# Controller wrapping in panel

Tags: c#

I have a panel with buttons. my buttons are create dynamically. I want to have 4 rows with 4 buttons each. but I only get one row.

```
 foreach (CategoriesDataSet.CategoriesRow category in DataRepository.Categories.Categories)
        {
            if (!category.CategoryName.Equals("ROOT"))
            {
                SimpleButton button = new SimpleButton();
                button.Text = category.CategoryName;
                button.Tag = category.CategoryId;
                button.Size = new Size(82, 70);


                if (lastButton != null)
                    button.Left = lastButton.Right + 1;


                lastButton = button;
                button.Click += CategoryButtonClick;
                categoriesPanel.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }
```

Desired result :

```
x x x x
X x x x 
x x x x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer followed by the comments of Treb's answer.
Use *for* loop and use **modulo** operator for *Left* property.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataRepository.Categories.Categories.Count; i++)
{
    CategoriesDataSet.CategoriesRow category = DataRepository.Categories.Categories[i];

        if (!category.CategoryName.Equals("ROOT"))
        {
            SimpleButton button = new SimpleButton();
            button.Text = category.CategoryName;
            button.Tag = category.CategoryId;
            button.Size = new Size(82, 70);

            button.Left = i%4*82;
            button.Top = i*70;

            button.Click += CategoryButtonClick;
            categoriesPanel.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only moving buttons to the right (horizontally) by adjusting the `Left` property:

```
button.Left = lastButton.Right + 1;
```

If you want to move them down, you need to adjust the vertical position instead:

```
button.Top = lastButton.Bottom + 1;
```

Since that way you leave the horizontal position unchanged, the new button should appear directly below the last one.

**EDIT:**
In answer to your comment, which result do you want? Is it A)

```
X X X X
```

or B)

```
X
X  
X  
X
```

or is it C)

```
X
 X  
  X  
   X
```

Or with *buttons by lines*, do you mean something like D)

```
X | X | X | X
```

or E)

```
X - X - X - X
```

Comment: Little typo in 1st row: you mean "adjusting `Left` property" ;-)

Comment: Hmpf, and that from the guy who beat me to the answer by 3 minutes!!! Thanks, corrected it ;-)

Comment: thank you for your response, but it doesn't work. Now, the buttons are placed vertically

Comment: But that's what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: No, I would like to have for example 4 buttons by lines

Comment: @MustafaE. Do you mean 4 buttons on every line?

Comment: @MustafaE. Then the best way is to use *for* instead of *foreach* like so `for (int i = 0; i < DataRepository.Categories.Categories.Count; i++)`. Within loop you define *category* so `CategoriesDataSet.CategoriesRow category = DataRepository.Categories.Categories[i]`. The *Left* property is set by `i%4*82` by using modulo operator *%*. The *Top* property is set by `i*70`.

Comment: @brgerner: You should edit your answer to incorporate the solution. , Mustafa: Once brgerner has done that, please accept his answer as the correct one.